# Switch Statement-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Please refer to the switch statement in JavaScript below and the same is not working.Please advise on the errors.

```
function main(arg1){   
    switch(arg1) {
        case 'Jatin':
            alert('This is Jatin');
        break;
        case 'Vivek':
            alert('This is Vivek');
        break;
        case 'Vikas':
            alert('This is Vikas');
        break;
        default:
            alert('The name is not found');
    };
    main("Jatin");
```

Comment: Please describe the error.

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket

Comment: Look up how the JavaScript error console works. It helps debugging a lot if you can see the error messages.

Comment: You are missing the ending `}` for your function `main`.

Comment: Thanks.Ya closing bracket was the issue.Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function main(arg1){   
     switch(arg1) {
         case 'Jatin':
             alert('This is Jatin');
         break;
         case 'Vivek':
             alert('This is Vivek');
         break;
         case 'Vikas':
             alert('This is Vikas');
         break;
         default:
             alert('The name is not found');
     } // no semi colon
} // closing brace

main("Jatin");
```